# How to set the list view position first when the button clicks?

Tags: android, listview

I want to do when the button clicks, the list listed from the top if click again it shows the last item

How to do this

sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reposition your list view use `setSelection`, something like:

```
position = data.lenght() - 1;
listView.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: the variable where you are storing the data shown in the list, (the one passed to the adapter)